# Pages 5.5.2: How do I remove the light gray line between two columns in a table?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, pages

I've inserted a 2 column Table into my Pages document. How would I remove the very faint light gray line that appears between the columns? This line is not just a formatting feature but shows up when I export the document to PDF.

Comment: Followup: Despite the font values being the same, the text inside the table appears thinner than text outside the table. Same font, same size, regular typeset, but the text inside the table looks like the opposite of bold (thin) while the text outside looks regular. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured out how to toggle gridlines. I am still unsure why the text appears differently in the table versus outside the table, despite sharing the same font and size.